# Unable to get all images using xpath

Tags: javascript, python, xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am trying to get all the images from this link https://www.residentialpeople.com/za/property/k2edgr-freehold/ however I cannot seem to get any. Even why I try to check for the request and JavaScript I cannot find where they are stored. Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Here is my initial approach:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="image-holder"]//@style').re(r'url\((.*)\);')
```

Comment: Why not just use the DOM instead of XPath?

Comment: Looks like all the content is dynamically loaded

Comment: @epascarello Yes, but I also cannot seem to get it while looking for API, not sure if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have everything you need inside JSON on the page:

```
import scrapy
import json

class ResidentialpeopleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'residentialpeople'
    start_urls = ['https://www.residentialpeople.com/za/property/k2edgr-freehold/']

    def parse(self, response):
        data_raw = response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').get()
        data = json.loads(data_raw)

        for image in data['@graph']['@graph'][0]['photo']:
            print(image['contentUrl'])
```